# PHP data Loading Issue

Tags: php

I am designing a PHP service which fetches data for using it in android.
The issue is when I run the query with Where Clause (id < 30) it's working. but when I change (id <40) I am getting a blank screen:

```
$return_arr = array();
$fe = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id, name FROM cable_channels where id < 30;");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fe)) {
  $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
  $row_array['name'] = $row['name'];
  array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Comment: What is the result you got from sql query when you change condition to id < 40 ? Did you get any response from mysql ?

Comment: @Ashok NO..Blank page

Comment: is it possible to be some server issue?? I am using godaddy

Comment: Have you tried to run this query in phpmyadmin and check the result ? Its not related to server issue i think

Comment: yes totally working

Comment: Try my answer and let me know what if that works

Comment: Try to change mysqli_query line to `mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id, name FROM cable_channels where id < 40"); or die(mysqli_error($conn));` and let us know what does it print?

Comment: @satish saini i am getting same output

Comment: Weird.. there is nothing wrong programmatically.. there must be something else at your end.. please check error logs and see whats coming there

Comment: yup..silly mistake While fetching data on id = 34 there was special character in database

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $return_arr = array();
    $fe = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id, name FROM cable_channels where id < 30;");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fe)) {
        $return_arr[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

Try above code, instead of using

> mysql_fetch_array

use

> mysql_fetch_assoc

and push all the values to array inside while loop.

Comment: Same Issue code is working but when i change id = 30 to id= 40 i am getting blank screen